# make my enemy spawn a little faster when reach a certain score

Tags: ios, swift, sprite-kit

```
func updateTimer() {
    if Score < 10 {
        runAction(SKAction.repeatActionForever(SKAction.sequence([SKAction.runBlock(addEnemy), SKAction.waitForDuration(1.0)])))
    }else if Score == 10 {
        runAction(SKAction.repeatActionForever(SKAction.sequence([SKAction.runBlock(addEnemy), SKAction.waitForDuration(0.5)])))
    }else if Score == 20 {
        runAction(SKAction.repeatActionForever(SKAction.sequence([SKAction.runBlock(addEnemy), SKAction.waitForDuration(0.1)])))
    }
}
```

i was trying to make the spawn faster when a player reach a certain score but this code has its error  can anyone help me with this please
thank you very much to whoever answers my question

i wanted to make it like this one

```
func updateTimer() {
    if score < 3 {
    timerDots = NSTimer.scheduledTimerWithTimeInterval(1.5, target: self, selector: "fireDot", userInfo: nil, repeats: true)

    // Dots get generated a bit faster than before after score reaches 3
    } else if score == 3 {
        timerDots?.invalidate()
        timerDots = NSTimer.scheduledTimerWithTimeInterval(1.0, target: self, selector: "fireDot", userInfo: nil, repeats: true)

    // Dots get generated even faster than before after score reaches 12
    } else if score == 12 {
        timerDots?.invalidate()
        timerDots = NSTimer.scheduledTimerWithTimeInterval(0.9, target: self, selector: "fireDot", userInfo: nil, repeats: true)
    }

}
```

Comment: Crashing error or the code just doesn't function as you want it to?

Comment: Are you sure you have initialized Score and that you have addEnemy closure / function.

Comment: "...this code has its error..." is a pretty useless description of what's going wrong. It gives your readers no information whatsoever. If you want help, provide a detailed description of what's going wrong. Otherwise we can't help.

Comment: sorry i just can't explain that good how can i make my enemy spawn faster and faster as the game go longer and longer or the score gets higher

Answer (score 1):

It's simpler to do this using an instance variable and the `SKScene` `update:` method:

```
private var score: Int = 0
private var priorEnemyAddTime: CFTimeInterval = 0

private var nextEnemyAddTime: CFTimeInterval {
    var waitTime = score < 10 ? 1.0
        : score < 20 ? 0.5
        : 0.1
    return priorEnemyAddTime + waitTime
}

override func update(currentTime: CFTimeInterval) {
    if nextEnemyAddTime <= currentTime {
        priorEnemyAddTime = currentTime
        addEnemy()
    }
}
```

On every frame, you check whether it's been long enough since the last time you added an enemy. If so, you save the current time as the time of last add, and add an enemy.

Comment: I'm sorry I'm still a noob on Xcode can you please explain it more like i don't know what private do i put that in my code too?

Comment: Do you know how to like I have 3 hero that you can choose to play with and which ever hero you choose that's the hero that your gonna use to play the game

Comment: It sounds like you need to post a separate top-level question for that.